# how to stop compass overwrite my css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass-sass

After I import `@import "compass";` in the `application.css.scss` file

And I include my own css in `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml`

my `GO Button` style has changed , how to fix it in an easier way?

I use Rails 4.0.2

[image]

[image]

How  could  I refactor my `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml`

```
  1 !!!
  2 %html
  3   %head
  4     %title GooodTheme
  5     = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
  6     = javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
  7     / Description, Keywords and Author
  8     %meta{content: "Your description", name: "description"}/
  9     %meta{content: "Your,Keywords", name: "keywords"}/
 10     %meta{content: "ResponsiveWebInc", name: "author"}/
 11     %meta{content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", name: "viewport"}/
 12     / Styles
 13     / Bootstrap CSS
 14     %link{href:  asset_path("css/bootstrap.min.css"), rel: "stylesheet"}/
 15     / Slider Revolution CSS
 16     %link{href:  asset_path("css/rs-settings.css"), rel: "stylesheet"}/
 17     /[if IE 8]
 18       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/rs-settings-ie8.css">
 19     / Animate CSS
 20     %link{href:  asset_path("css/animate.min.css"), rel: "stylesheet"}/
 21     / Portfolio CSS
 22     %link{href:  asset_path("css/prettyPhoto.css"), rel: "stylesheet"}/
 23     / Font awesome CSS
 24     %link{href:  asset_path("css/font-awesome.min.css"), rel: "stylesheet"}/
 25     / Custom CSS
 26     %link{href:  asset_path("css/style.css"), rel: "stylesheet"}/
 27     / Favicon
 28     %link{href:  asset_path("#"), rel: "shortcut icon"}/
 29     = csrf_meta_tags
 30   %body
 31     / = render 'layouts/revolution_bar'
 32     / = render 'layouts/service'
 33     / = render 'layouts/about_us'
 34     / = render 'layouts/projects'
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the order in which your CSS files are imported. Files loaded latter overrides the files that was loaded first.

Comment: Hey what if my own css included in the `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml`

Comment: @poc you need to move those CSS out of HAML and place them separately. You will be able to customize the order.

Comment: how could I refactor my `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml`, could you give me some directions, thanks

Comment: you should not place css files in application.haml, place them in application.css by using asset pipeline - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html